# Cant convert onetoone to onetomany in doctrine using symfony2

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got hired about 2 weeks in a company, and my first task was to update and implement new features in an existing software written in symfony2-doctrine. But one of the changes I must make is just breaking my back.

The previous model was: one "cliente" (costumer) could have only one "credito" (credit) and one "credito" could have many "venta" (sales)
The new model should be: one "cliente" (costumer) can have many "credito" and one "credito" can have many "venta" (Im keeping the onetomany association for backwards compatibity)

This is how my entities look like this:

cliente.php

```
class Cliente {
//put your code here
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

 /**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $nombre;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $documento;


/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)    
 */
protected $direccion;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)     
 */
protected $telefono;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)     
 */
protected $celular;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
protected $email;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)

 */
protected $ciudad;


/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)

 */
protected $departamento;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)

 */
protected $referenciaFamiliar;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)

 */
protected $referenciaFamiliarTelefono;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)

 */
protected $referenciaPersonal;


/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)

 */
protected $referenciaPersonalTelefono;


/**   
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Credito", mappedBy="cliente", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $credito;



/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true, length=255)     
 */
protected $photo;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="300k", mimeTypes={"image/jpeg","image/png"},mimeTypesMessage="Debe subir una imagen JPG o PNG",maxSizeMessage="La imagen no puede pesar más de 300 kb.")
 */

protected $file;
```

credito.php

```
class Credito {
//put your code here
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $cc;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",nullable=false)
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
protected $fechaRegistro;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cliente",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cliente_id",referencedColumnName="id")     
 */
protected $cliente;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Venta", mappedBy="credito",cascade={"all"})         
 */
protected $ventas;

/**   
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Abono", mappedBy="credito",cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $abonos;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",nullable=true)
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
protected $fechaProximoPago;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",scale=3, precision=23)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $valorProximoPago;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $cuotasTotales;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $cuotasPagadas;



/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ModoPagoNom")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modo_pago_id",referencedColumnName="id")  

 */
protected $modoPago;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",scale=3, precision=23)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $valorFinanciado;


/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",scale=3, precision=23)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $cupo;


/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",scale=3, precision=23)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $cupoUsado;
```

venta.php

```
class Venta{
//put your code here
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

 /**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
protected $fecha;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
protected $fechaPrimerPago;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $numeroFactura;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $numeroAutorizo;




/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",scale=3, precision=23)
 * @Assert\Min(limit="0", message="El valor de la factura debe ser positivo")
 */
protected $valorFactura;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\Type("integer")
 * @Assert\Min(limit="1", message="Debe especificar al menos una cuota")
 */
protected $numeroCuotas;


/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\Min(0)
 */
protected $cuotasPagadas;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ModoPagoNom")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modo_pago_id",referencedColumnName="id")  

 */
protected $modoPago;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Credito",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="credito_id",referencedColumnName="id")     
 */
protected $credito;


/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",scale=3, precision=23)
 * @Assert\Min(0.0)
 */
protected $valorFinanciado;

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",scale=3, precision=23)
 * @Assert\Min(0.0)
 */
protected $valorCuota;    

/**   
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal",scale=3, precision=23)
 * @Assert\Min(0.0)
 */
protected $valorPrimeraCuota; 

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Almacen")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="almacen_id",referencedColumnName="id")        
 */
protected $almacen;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
```

**The problem is:** everytime I insert a new "credito", it wont be linked to the existing "cliente" instead of that, it will try to insert a duplicate entry of "cliente".
I've tried many things but none of them had any effect.

I appreciate any help, cause Im stuck with that.
If further information or code is required I will gladly provide it.

Comment: Try adding `inversedBy="credito"` to your ManyToOne annotation in credito.php

Answer (score 2):

The `cascade={"persist"}` should be the core of your problem:

```
class Credito {
......
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cliente",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cliente_id",referencedColumnName="id")     
 */
protected $cliente;
```

It tells doctrine to persist cleinte always when you persist Credito.
See docs for more details http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Answer (score 0):

Always tell Doctrine how to do in both sides of an association :

```
// credito.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cliente", inversedBy="credito", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cliente_id",referencedColumnName="id")     
 */
protected $cliente;
```

And

```
// venta.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Credito", inversedBy="ventas", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="credito_id",referencedColumnName="id")     
 */
protected $credito;
```